# SQL query to get filtered list based on maximum value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm hoping for some fresh eyes on this.  I've been trying to nut this query out for the best part of a day and still can't figure out the answer.
Using SQL Server 2012.

I've got a data table

[image]

What I want to get out is a list of the recordID of the maximum version number for each sourcerecordID

From the example above I would get 2, 5, 7, 9, 10
Like I said, I'm really at a loss how to get this result so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy. Use `ROW_NUMBER` window function

```
Select recordID From
(
select row_number()over(partition by sourcerecordID Order by versionnumber desc) RN,*
From yourtable
)A
Where RN = 1
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after.  Did not know about the "Over" approch

Answer (score 0):

The Question you ask and the Result you need is mismatched.

Here the answer for the question you ask.

```
select SourceRecordId,max(VersionNumber) VersionNumber from ver
group by SourceRecordId
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at it, apologies for the mistake in my question.  However your solution does not meet the requirements.  I need the recordID of the max version number.  This will only provide the sourcerecordID